# Send task to multiple recipients on exchange server using EWS Managed API 2.0

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server

Does anyone know how to send a Task programmatically in C# to several mailboxes on an Exchange Server using EWS Managed API 2.0?

Comment: What do yea mean task? can please provide a scenario of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have done plenty of research on Google.  If you are familiar with the EWS Managed API, you know that there is a Task class that you can instantiate and store in mailbox folders on an exchange server.  I am able to save the Task in my task folder on the exchange server but I am not able to assign a task (like in Outlook) to someone else on the exchange server.  I can attach a Task to an EmailMessage and send the EmailMessage to several people, though. I would like the same behavior as when assigning a task in Outlook.  The task is sent to a person and shows up in their inbox.